# Display array value on html by row

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How to map an array by displaying it by rows?

```
var data = [28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23]
```

Output:
[image]

This is my code for rearranging the array

```
const positionRearrange = (data) => {
const
  result = [],
  swap = { unshift: 'push', push: 'unshift' }

  data
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .forEach((fn => v => result[fn = swap[fn]](v))('unshift'))

  return result 
}
```

Comment: NICE, what did you try?

Comment: @OmriAttiya still finding the solution but already finish the sorting just mapping the data into rows is the problem

const positionRearrange = (data) => {
    const
      result = [],
      swap = { unshift: 'push', push: 'unshift' }

      data
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .forEach((fn => v => result[fn = swap[fn]](v))('unshift'))

      return result 
  }

Comment: Add your code to the question so we all can see that

Comment: I don't understand your ordering? 27, 28, 26 ?

Comment: @SteveTomlin you can use the function I included

Comment: @Angelica When you ask a question here on S.O. you should always add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And make sure your question is without a doubt understandable by everyone. Maybe add titles/sections like "This is what I tried:" or "This is what it should look like:" etc. For now, it is not really clear what the desired logic is.

Comment: @F.Müller noted sir

Comment: Do you want the items to be sorted of sorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cteated a function which loops for 3 values in a row and then creates  multiple arrays for each of them ( 3 value filled array )  , finally rearrange the array elements as required .
For selecting only first three values ( or creating  ranges) we use `array.slice(start, end)`

**Solution =>**

```
  let data = [28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23]

  function slicing () {
    let arr_data = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 3) {
      let arr = data.slice(i, i + 3).sort()
      let v1 = arr[0];
      let v2 = arr[1];
      let v3 = arr[2];
      arr = [v1,
        v3,
        v2]
      arr_data.push(arr)
    }
    console.log(arr_data)
  }
  slicing()
```

Comment: @Angelica is it what you wanted ?

Comment: yes sir like this, now my only problem is making this dynamic

Comment: @Angelica What do you mean with "dynamic"? What kind of sorting do you want to apply?

Comment: @Angelica yay me too can't understand by dynamic ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split your data into chunks of (sorted) n-items you can run one of the snippets below:

### Modern way - using array.slice()

```js
const data = [28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23];
const rowSize = 3;
const chunks = Array();
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += rowSize) {
  const row = data.slice(i, i + rowSize).sort();
  chunks.push(row);
}
console.log(chunks);
```

### Old-Skool way

Most of the time performance is not an issue but this way shown below is a little bit faster. And depending on whatever you are trying to do it might be a vital alternative.

```js
const data = [28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23];
const rowSize = 3; // How many elements fit into one row
const numberOfRows = Math.floor(data.length / rowSize);
const chunks = Array(numberOfRows); // Allocate memory for n-rows

// Create a 2D-array for each row we allocate memory for n-items => rowSize
for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
  chunks[i] = Array(rowSize);
}

// Loop over the elements in data and compute the corresponding row and column index
for (i in data) {
  const rowIndex = Math.floor(i / rowSize);
  const colIndex = i - rowIndex * rowSize;
  chunks[rowIndex][colIndex] = data[i];
}

// If you want to sort your rows
for (i in chunks) {
  chunks[i].sort();
}

console.log(chunks);
```